# PInvoke and return string from c++ dll into C# application

Tags: c#, string, pinvoke

I'm writting C wrapper to C++ class to expose it to C# code using PInvoke. I found some interesting thing and I would like to know why this code behaves like this. Question is why c_str return empty value?

```
// c_++ class
class Foo
{
public:
    method returns m_fullName
    std::string fullName() const;
private:
    const std::string m_fullName;
};


extern "C" const char* fullNameFoo(Foo* object)
{
    if (object != NULL)
    {
        // this return empty string - but why? class exists so fullName exists too
        return object->fullName().c_str();

        // returns proper value
        return strcpy(new char[object->fullName().size()], object->fullName().c_str());
    }

    return NULL;
}

// C# code
[DllImport("mylib.dll", EntryPoint = "fullNameFoo")]
static public extern IntPtr FullNameFoo(IntPtr foo);
```

Comment: Standard c language a string is a byte[] array terminate with '\0'.   C++ using net library strings is the same class as in c# which is a one/two byte character with a private properly indicating if character is one or two bytes.

Comment: I know it. Question is related why object->fullName().c_str() doesn't return value throught pinvoke to c# code and I have to make a copy array.

Comment: Neither are valid. Certainly not that use of c_str. The pointer is invalid when the function ends. The second version fails to copy null terminator and forces you to also export a deallocator. Correct way to do this is to have the caller allocate the buffer.

Comment: @jdweng That's a really misleading and unhelpful comment. One of a long series you have made in pinvoke questions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for comment. But I have another question. fullName method returns internal member of class. This also returns a copy of pointer which is not valid after move out of scope method? I thought that this will return pointer to internal array of char and it will be valid after return from function.